# How to use character as variable name in arguments? [R]

Tags: r, string, variable-names

I am wondering how to tell R the string I used in the arguments of a function stands for a variable instead of the string itself. Specifically, I am dealing with 'Dict' package and run the following code as a trial.

```
library(Dict)
x  = c(1,2)

d = dict(x = 1)
d$keys
# 'x'
```

What I want is `c(1,2)` to be the key instead of `'x'`. The same problem goes for 'list', for example

```
y = 'happy'
l = list(y = 1)

names(l)
```

The result would be `'y'`. Moreover, one can solve this situation by
`names(l) <- y`, but I don't think this is very efficient and clean.

Anyone has any idea how to do this in a one-line code? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `setNames`

```
out <- do.call(dict, setNames(rep(list(1), length(x)), x))
out$keys
[1] "1" "2"
```

---

Or we may use `invoke` or `exec`

```
library(purrr)
out <- invoke(dict, setNames(rep(1, length(x)), x))
out <- exec(dict, !!!setNames(rep(1, length(x)), x))
```

---

For the second case, also `setNames` works

```
setNames(list(1), y)
$happy
[1] 1
```

or we can use `dplyr::lst`

```
dplyr::lst(!! y := 1)
$happy
[1] 1
```